# Extra arguments in Metaclass

Tags: python, metaprogramming, metaclass

I wrote the following metaclass:

```
class FieldHandlerBase(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct, model):
        ...
        return super(FieldHandlerBase, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)
```

Now, I try to dynamically create a class using the above metaclass:

```
FieldHandlerBase(
    '%sFieldHandler' % name,
    (FieldHandler,),
    {rel_type: dct.setdefault(rel_type, ()) for rel_type in REL_TYPES},
    model=name)
```

But it throws me this error:

```
>           model=name)
E       TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
E           type.__init__() takes no keyword arguments
```

I don't understand why, since I call the metaclass base (`type` here, from within `FieldHandlerBase`) with the correct number of arguments. How can I fix this? I need to pass an extra argument to `FieldHandlerBase` and I don't want to include it into the `dct` argument, since I need it only at metaclass level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write an `__init__` method as well as a `__new__` method. Otherwise, python will call `type.__init__` for your new class, which does not take any additional arguments.

eg.

```
class FieldHandlerBase(type):

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs, model):
        type.__init__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        cls.model = model

    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, attrs, model):
        ...
        return type.__new__(metacls, name, bases, attrs)

class ExampleFieldHandler(FieldHandler, metaclass=FieldHandlerBase, 
        model="Example"):
    clsvar = "var"

# or 
ExampleFieldHandler = FieldHandlerBase(
    "ExampleFieldHandler",
    (FieldHandler,),
    {"clsvar": "var"},
    model="Example"
)

assert ExampleFieldHandler.model == "Example"
```

Comment: Oh, I thought the `__init__()` will be called with the same arguments as `__new__()`. Thank you!

Comment: It is. And that's the problem. Since you hadn't defined your own `__init__` the `__init__` on the superclass (type) was called. The `__init__` on type doesn't accept model as a parameter and so the call fails.

Comment: I was referring to the second call of `__new__()`, the one I make to the superclass (`type`), and where I precisely leave out the `model` argument. But if I understand correctly, the calls to `__new__()` and `__init__()` are dispatched from some other place and they both have the same arguments regardless of what I do in those two methods. Now, out of curiosity, who exactly dispatches the calls to `__new__()` and `__init__()`?

Comment: That's right. `type` implements `__call__` which dispatches both the calls. You can check it out by doing `type.__call__(YourMetaclass, names, bases, attrs, yourargs)`